# Emacs hook for new frames

Tags: emacs, window

I need a command to run whenever a new frame is created in Emacs. So far I've been using `after-make-frame-functions`, but this hook only gets called on frames created by `make-frame`. **I actually need something that runs whenever the `emacsclient -c` command creates a new window.**

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm having some difficulty understanding your question. The Emacs server calls `make-frame` when it needs to create a new frame, so `after-make-frame-functions` should work in that case too. So what's your actual problem?

Is it that you want your function to run even if the Emacs server *doesn't* create a new frame? If so, try adding your function to `server-switch-hook` as well as `after-make-frame-functions`.

> `server-switch-hook` is a variable defined in `server.el`.
>
> Documentation: Hook run when switching to a buffer for the Emacs
>   server.

Comment: Yes, your first paragraph is correct. The command I wanted to run works perfectly when I do `make-frame`, but it just wasn't working when a new frame was created with `emacsclient -c`. So I just assumed that the hook wasn't called by the server when I ran `emacsclient -c`. I did I bit more testing now, and it turns out there's just something wrong with my command. Sorry for the senseless question.

Comment: No problem. [Rubber duck debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) in action!

Comment: Amazing! I introduce to you the concept of meta rubber duck debugging by proxy, where someone -- e.g. myself -- finds someone with the exact same problem on SO and discovers the problem doesn't actually exist. I am indebted to both of you.